# How with faker to get text without ending “.”?

Tags: laravel, faker

When in laravel 9 app I set value for text field with faker :

```
 $this->faker->unique()->text(25);
```

I see text for field ending with “.”.
How can I get text without ending “.” ?

```
"laravel/framework": "^9.11",
"fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author of the library decided not to implement this feature: https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker/issues/1128

You can do it like:

```
substr(str_replace('.', '', $this->faker->unique()->text(25)), 0, 25);
```

You can adjust this to replace with specific symbol, if you need to have exactly 25 chars.